# modal not right in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

This problem only exists in IE, it works fine in chrome

I have an iframe wich shows a pdf file:

```
<iframe src='myRoute/mypdf.com' width="100%" height="435px" id="PDF" name="PDF" title="Visor PDF" style="z-index:-1;" allowTransparency="true" wmode="opaque" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

It works fine in IE, but if I a modal is show:

```
HTML:
   <div aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade in" id="myModal" style="display: block;">
     <div class="col-xs-10 texto">
        <p>text alert</p>
     </div>    
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="modalButton" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button> 
   </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#myModal').modal("show");
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.fade.in {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

The pdf document is not behind the modal, and it's shown as if its z-index were bigger than the modal's.

[image: ie modal]

Is there any solution for this IE problem?

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: IE 11, I update the post to add an image

Comment: This bug occurs in any version of IE, and there's no fix. As a workaround, I've set `display: none` to iframes showing PDF, if I've to show something over it.